# How to get union of value types of a nested object?

Tags: typescript

Given an object like this:

```
const deepNestedObject = {
  a: "value",
  b: {
    c: "nestedvalue"
    d: {
       e: "deepNestedValue"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I generate a union type of specifically only the non-object values at the edge

```
type EdgeValueUnion = DeepValueOf<typeof deepNestedObject>; // Should equate to "value" | "nestedValue" | "deepNestedValue"
```

So far I've tried this:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

type DeepValueOf<
  T extends Record<string, unknown>,
  Key = keyof T
> = Key extends string
  ? T[Key] extends Record<string, unknown>
    ? DeepValueOf<T[Key]>
    : ValueOf<T>
  : never;
```

but it's not quite right because it still allows object values in the tree to pass. e.g.

```
const edgeValue: EdgeValueUnion = deepNestedObject.b;
```

[Sample TS sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QPIDMA8AVAfFAXimwG0BrCEAe3WIF0BuAKCdEigBEIIx5k0sTKMSgQAHsAgA7ACYBnKACUIAYyoAnGZjnB1ASykBzADRQkUslKoB3KbmNCoAaUqEoFarWxN8RFyFEJaXkoHX0jRwB+YhJ-OkDJWQVlNU1tXQMTMwsrW1xHYWiuHj4UDBxYyjp84WEALlhEMqw8RwapCAA3CHVmJjUpHSh1CHQe6RU0ACMAK1VgNwBvRzgGgCJOpogARjWHYSmG5dqoGW4wdc3+ACY9gqg4K2AACx7LrYBmO5O5JEh1YoXKDHE5QAC2Ggg6w6Oky31qAF9HEiEQ8FAMdH02NBlOhULN5m5sTRhqNxlJJvi5ipgFjwNAAKIyQwQUoQbD0tyAtnlXFU+a4PoAeiFUAAclQOlASS8IHJoHJnlQkAgZFAnlAptAwFQ5HI9FMEBB+pKhhBmayttsGkyWWyOewiCMxiMKdNqcAAHRTBhQEVQFSPBYshYvPQKYBUKDoOB6BBQOoAChNgwW5rtW2uNot9s5RDW5ksNikAForig1r7-TG4wo4ApxJAaeaWP7sK95aElSq1Yh41rowZjRi0znPtmM-wHdAnWTXZSCTTPXBmCPRGP+AAWCeWqd50kuibu+bez1nHir02jycoACsO9zjoP5IXHtPv3+gM9EJGDCAA)

Comment: Your union here would just be string, since that's the only type of value your keys map to. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract all the strings from the values:

```
type EdgeValueUnion = Extract<DeepValueOf<typeof deepNestedObject>, string>;
```

You also need a const assertion to make sure the strings are inferred as literals instead of the general `string` type:

```
const deepNestedObject = {
    a: "value",
    b: {
        c: "nestedvalue",
        d: {
            e: "deepNestedValue",
        },
    },
} as const;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QPIDMA8AVAfFAXimwG0BrCEAe3WIF0BuAKCdEigBEIIx5k0s2KBAAewCADsAJgGcoAJQgBjKgCcpmGcFUBLCQHMANFCQSyEqgHcJuYwGlKhKBWq08ThyGFjJsqFt0DJigQqAB+YhJPOm9xaTlFFXVNbT0jEzMLa1xg0LyIrh4+FAwcKMo6HLy8gC5YRBLBKtC6iQgANwhVZlZwaABRKX0IYogAVQkdKgknfrFVOCVgTELeBoFMNggaKCluMAA5CC0IKVQAIwArZWBbf1SDXB6VCS1d-aOTs6ubpwBvXIhOB1ABE7XWIMMgKg5zqAOqoSUoLaX3B-Eh0LyUjhmIRwlBex4n3EUlGGLxUAAvlC8tSmJSoHA5C8tM9pm9TsNRnVBlz1hMpjMiITDscSRdrksAHTnZhAA)

Comment: Well that was fast. Yes this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I can't even mark it as the solution yet it was so fast. TIL about Extract